# Can I make an inline element in AMP that loads data from a web API?

Tags: amp-html

I have site where editors may use a [display_phone] shortcode to insert a phone number into text. The number varies based on cookies the viewer may have; we make an AJAX call to get the desired number.

I'm trying to replicate this on an AMP page. I've done it successfully with an `amp-list` element, however, that's a `block` element. I want an `inline` element that will inherit font size and other styles from its parent. I tried forcing the `amp-list` to `inline` or `inline-block`, but it applies styles to elements inside its template that can't be overridden.

I looked into using other elements for display and using `amp-state` as a data source, but `amp-bind` doesn't run without user input, and I need this phone number to show before any input. I could conceivably create an `amp-list` for every block-level section where an editor could insert the shortcode, but that seems like a bad idea.

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: We have a similar problem and have filed a feature request: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/23675 Suggest you also file an FR.